# UIBarbuttonitem selector never gets triggered (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift

Sometimes the simplest things prove the hardest to work out! The picker is displayed when users select the user location text field but the selectors are not working. Gone through SO and Apple docs but can't work out why this is.

```
let locationPicker = UIPickerView()
var locationData = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set textfield delegate
    userID.delegate = self
    userLocation.delegate = self

    // Set up picker view for location selection
    locationPicker.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 140)
    locationPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.closePicker(sender:)))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.closePicker(sender:)))

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackOpaque
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true

    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    userLocation.inputView = locationPicker
    userLocation.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    // Load locations into array
    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("venues")
    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        // Pull out the keys to represent locations
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshots {
                print("snap key, \(snap.key) and snap value \(snap.value)")
                let loc : String = snap.key
                self.locationData.append(loc)
            }
        }

        // Now stick the array of locations into the picker view
        self.locationPicker.dataSource = self
        self.locationPicker.delegate = self
        self.locationPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    })
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.endEditing(true)
    return false
}

func closePicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Close picker")
    self.locationPicker.isHidden = true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let iText = userID.text,  let lText = userLocation.text, !iText.isEmpty, !lText.isEmpty
    {
        print("We have data")
        // loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // loginButton.alpha = 1.0
    }
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return locationData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return locationData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    userLocation.text = locationData[row]
}
```

Comment: try `#selector(closePicker(_:))`

Comment: @Tj3n I think doing that will throw an error in Swift 3, since he has not prefixed the argument in the function `closePicker` with an underscrore like `closePicker(_ sender: UIButton)`

Comment: @ebby94 Yep, didnt noticed that, but i just tried and it seems to work fine with `self.` also, unsure what's the problem in this case